# How to browse a video from video library in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

i have video application where i want to Browse video from video library.Can anybody please help me in solving this problem on how to browse for particular video from video library in iphone.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UIImagePickerController`:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
picker.delegate = self; // don't forget implement UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods
[picker presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
```

Read [Camera Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406) for more details

Comment: You've set `kUTTypeMovie` for media types of your UIImagePickerControl. That will force showing only videos from library

Comment: It's a separate question. [Use all power of Google search](http://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&newwindow=1&q=iphone+play+video+from+library+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aq=o&aqi=&aql=&oq=) Here you can find, that you cannot do that

Answer (score -3):

Here is our .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 


#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface AudioAndVideoViewController : UIViewController{ 
@public
}
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

- (IBAction) startPlayingVideo:(id)paramSender;

- (IBAction) stopPlayingVideo:(id)paramSender;

@end


- (IBAction) startPlayingVideo:(id)paramSender{

NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *urlAsString = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"m4v"];

if (self.moviePlayer != nil)
{
[self stopPlayingVideo:nil];
}
MPMoviePlayerController *newMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

self.moviePlayer = newMoviePlayer; [newMoviePlayer release]; if (self.moviePlayer != nil){

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoHasFinishedPlaying:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayer];


NSLog(@"Successfully instantiated the movie player.");

 self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

 [self.moviePlayer play];

[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

[self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

}
 else {

NSLog(@"Failed to instantiate the movie player.");
}
}

- (IBAction) stopPlayingVideo:(id)paramSender 
{

 if (self.moviePlayer != nil){
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayer];

[self.moviePlayer stop];

if (self.moviePlayer.view != nil && self.moviePlayer.view.superview != nil &&[self.moviePlayer.view.superview isEqual:self.view] == YES)
{

[self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
}}
```

Comment: is that right i didn't think so.Rocky asking for Browsing not for the NSString *urlAsString = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"m4v"];

Comment: Bad formatted answer. A lot of unnecessary, overloading details. Voting down